# One-to-one relashionship Entity Framework and .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

I am creating a relationship between my classes using code first. The integration happens with MySql, however, after migrating it consider the relationship as one-to-many when I check my workbench ERD.

How can I make a relashionship one-to-one using the classes mentioned below?

Here is my code:

```
public class About  
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int Userid { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string about_file { get; set; }
    public string about_desc { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User 
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string login { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public virtual About About { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Offers> Offers { get; set; } = new List<Offers>();
    public ICollection<Portfolio> Portifolios { get; set; } = new List<Portfolio>();
}
```

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore   Version:    {5.0.7}

[image: Image from my ERD generated by workbench]

Comment: This is a great learning resource for EF:Core.  https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-one-relationship-configuration

Comment: Knowing the exact EF version would also be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've just edited my post.  

The version is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Version: {5.0.7}  

And I'm already read this page but did not have any success, at the moment I'm following the Microsoft Doc.  but with no success as well... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 2):

It is a one-to-one relationship by convention only. Having a navigation property instead of a collection, ensures that only one child entity can be related to one parent from Entity Framework's perspective. But on the database level, there is nothing that prevents the creation of multiple child entities.

If you want to enforce it on the database level, add a UNIQUE constraint to the foreign key on the child entity, or make the primary keys on both entities identical and make that the foreign key instead.

Comment: Right.  The db-design is the same.  The unique constraint on the FK is the big difference.

Comment: @Irpe Thanks for your reply, I've tried that changing my About class the following code but it is still showing me one-to many... public class About { [Key] [ForeignKey("User")] public int Userid { get; set; }